# How does select() modify its input sets?

Tags: c, sockets, select, network-programming

I know select modifies the input sets upon return. But how?
How will a fd that's in an input set become not in the input set? fd_isset(fd) will return true, it seems to me, as long as fd was in the input set at the beginning. So how exactly does select() modify its input sets?

This is the fd_set structure:

```
typedef struct fd_set {
  u_int  fd_count;
  SOCKET fd_array[FD_SETSIZE];
} fd_set;
```

So which fields will be updated by select()? We still want to track all of the fd's so I don't see how it makes sense for select() to change fd_count or fd_array? So, what DOES select() change?

From man page:

"On exit, the sets are modified in place to indicate which file descriptors actually changed status."

But details about WHAT aspect of the sets are modified are glaringly missing.

EDIT:
**In response to the answers:
So is the following the correct way of using this?**

```
while (not error and not socket closes){
    FD_ZERO(&readSet);
    FD_ZERO(&writeSet);
    FD_SET(fd, &readSet);
    FD_SET(socket_num, &readSet);
    FD_SET(fd, &writeSet);
    FD_SET(socket_num, &writeSet);
    select(nfds, &readSet, writeSet, NULL, NULL);
    if(FD_ISSET(fd, &readSet)){
      read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
      write(socket_num, buf, sizeof(buf));
      /*memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));*/
    }
    if(FD_ISSET(socket_num, &readSet)){
      read(socket_num, buf, sizeof(buf));
      write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please suggest relevant tags. The only one I can think of is c...

Comment: "which file descriptors actually changed status" is very clear to me. Why would the count be modified?

Comment: Other than missing one `&`, the code you inserted in your update appears as if it could be  a valid way of using `select()`.  Whether it actually is valid depends on many details of the context in which that code appears.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The context in which the code appears is the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762852/in-c-proxy-http-requests-to-another-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On input, the `fd_set` tells `select()` which FDs it should be checking. `select` makes a copy of this list for its internal use. When it returns, it modifies the input structure to contain the returned information. It can modify both `fd_count` and `fd_array`.

This is why loops that use `select()` typically save a copy of the `fd_set` before the loop, and copy this back to the variable that's used in the `select()` call each time through the loop, e.g.

```
FD_SET(sockfd, &fd_set_init);
while(true) {
    FD_COPY(&fd_set_init, &fd_set);
    n = select(nfds, &fd_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (n > 0) {
        // Use fd_set here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question.

Comment: You're missing `&` before `writeset` in the `select` call. But otherwise it's right.

Comment: Thanks. I'll link my full code here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762852/in-c-proxy-http-requests-to-another-server

Answer (score 2):

The `select()` function takes *pointers* to the various file descriptor sets among its arguments.  It can modify the FD sets via those pointers in the same way that any function can modify the referent of any pointer passed to it.  Given the `fd_set` definition you provided, it would probably do so by writing to the appropriate elements of the `fd_array` member *[update:] and possibly to the `fd_count` member as well.*

Note, however, that it is incorrect to say that the structure definition you provided is **the** `fd_set` structure.  Presumably you pulled it from a header file relevant to you, so it is **an** `fd_set` structure, but the structure definition is not documented, so it may be implemented differently on other systems.  This is one reason why the `FD_*()` functions are provided for manipulating these structures' contents.

Particularly relevant to your question, you can use `FD_ISSET()` to test the contents of the file descriptor sets after `select()` returns.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very helpful.

Comment: Specifically, it looks like the `fd_set` structure from Windows.